# unix command (grep,cut)

Tags: unix

I have this file "auto" content:

renault :Clio :1999 :25000 :9000 :rouge
peugeot :106 :2000 :15000 :10000 :bleue
citroen :AX :1994 :55000 :5000 :gris
wolswagen :golf4 :2000 :10000 :22000 : bleue
mercedes :Classe C :2002 :5000 :43000 : gris
renault :Clio :1993 :65000 :6000 :bleue
wolswagen :golf3 :1995 :58000 :8000 : bleue

so,the question is "how can i display the list of models (2nd field) File "auto" identifying for everyone the number of vehicles ?"

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are a few different ways, such as awk which can do this.

Comment: what is awk ,is that a command ?

Comment: It's a command-line tool for processing lines, from wikipedia: The AWK utility is a data extraction and reporting tool that uses a data-driven scripting language consisting of a set of actions to be taken against textual data (either in files or data streams) for the purpose of producing formatted reports.

Comment: An awk script can do this.  I havent worked with it for a while so couldn't give you a script to run. A tutorial may be available to help you with it.  If you do get it going, please post it if possible. ;)

Comment: @sehe this is a programming related question.

Comment: @maalem - this link should give you a good start: http://unstableme.blogspot.com/2010/03/awk-count-and-sum-on-multiple-columns.html

Comment: @Russel: you're so right. I read the 'awk' question and assumed it was directed at the asker. It wasn't :)

Answer (score 2):

Try the script `count`:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
  col = 2
  freq[$col]++
}
END {
  for (word in freq)
    printf "%s\t%d\n", word, freq[word]
}
```

which, after running is: `count data.txt`, will print:

```
:106        1
:Clio       2
:AX         1
:golf3      1
:Classe     1
:golf4      1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 cut -d ':' -f 2 auto | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

This time I tested it:

```
sehe@meerkat:/tmp$ cut -d ':' -f 2 auto | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
      1 106 
      1 AX 
      1 Classe C 
      1 golf3 
      1 golf4 
      2 Clio
```

Comment: 1 106 
      1 AX 
      1 Classe C 
      1 Clio 
      1 Clio 
      1 golf3 
      1 golf4

Comment: it repeats the same car twice ?

Comment: i want 2 Clio not 1 Clio 1 Clio

Comment: O dang, i forgot (how is that possible) to sort, fixed

Answer (score 0):

thanks all ,i edited this code after combining some responses :

`cut -f2 -d: auto|sort|uniq -c`

and i get the searched result:

1 106
 1 AX
 1 Classe C
 2 Clio
 1 golf3
 1 golf4